# Google AMP Validation shows "Unknown syntax error" for amp-html

Tags: validation, amp-html

So, the page url is 
https://shop-europa.ru/amp/catalog/dtl-shtany-athletic-surplus-chyernyy-sp-0004/#development=1
Other validators, like [ampporject validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/), show everything is OK, but
google amp validation is not

What's wrong? Does anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

I see `AMP Validation successful` on the `#development=1` page myself, so it looks like this page is valid AMP. What error do you see?

Can you try refreshing the page in your browser, you may have a stale copy of the AMP Validator.

The only other thing I can think of is that the server is delivering different content to you (based on useragent, cookie, ip, etc) than to other users of the page, like myself.

Comment: Page is also correctly cached: https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/shop-europa.ru/amp/catalog/dtl-shtany-athletic-surplus-chyernyy-sp-0004/